# Android: Can't add new In-App products to application...?

Tags: java, android, permissions, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am making a game with in-app purchasing for extra levels.  I have implemented all of the necessary code and the test purchases work perfectly.   However when I go to add the products to my (unpublished) app I get the following message on the android developer dashboard:

"New in-app products cannot be added because the current application version does not use the BILLING permission."

These are the permissions I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />
```

So I can't understand why I am getting this message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am trying to release the game this weekend and this is my last barrier.

Thanks in advance, and rest assured I WILL accept an answer, I know people on here get worried about that sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the permission. Use

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

It looks like your app gets all the permissions it needs. My advice is to make sure that the uploaded version of the app is the current version, and also that you are logged in using your Google Checkout Merchant account (this is different from a regular Google or Google Checkout account) as referenced [By the docs.](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html) Hope this helps!

Comment: Figured it out myself, since you were the only one to answer you get the correct checkmark.

Comment: The problem was it should just be  
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

Comment: @rjacks i had same biling permisin but yet not able to add product